# How can I show the complete symmetric quadratic form has no zeros?

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

The quadratic [complete symmetric homogeneous polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial) in $n$ variables $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ is defined to be
$$h_2(t_1,\ldots,t_n) := \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k \leq n} t_j t_k = \sum_{j=1}^n t_j^2 + \sum_{j<k} t_j t_k.$$

For example, in one variable we have $h_2(t_1) = t_1^2$, in two variables
$$h_2(t_1,t_2) = t_1^2 + t_2^2 + t_1 t_2,$$ and in three 
$$h_2(t_1,t_2,t_3) = t_1^2 + t_2^2 + t_3^2 + t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1.$$

By a theorem of Jacobi, any quadratic form is conjugate (by an orthogonal transformation) to a diagonal one. It turns out that $h_2(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is conjugate to one with one eigenvalue $\frac{n+1}2$ and the others $\frac 1 2$, so **there are no nontrivial zeros**.

I came to this question through trying to see if there are any **integer** solutions. **Is there a more clean** (perhaps modular) **way of seeing there are no integer solutions to $h_2 = 0$?**

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159506/positive-definite-quadratic-form

Comment: Wow, this is basically the same question. I looked for similar questions first; how did I miss this?!

Comment: Can write the solution $x^2+y^2+z^2+q^2=xy+xz+xq+yz+yq+zq$ such equation? If Yes, how?

Comment: @individ, I'm not sure I understand your question, but mine is essentially whether the left-hand side of your equation can be *minus* the right-hand side, with solutions in integers. And the answer to my question was no.

Comment: As I know, decision no. There are solutions for this equation: $a(x^2+y^2+z^2)=b(xy+xz+yz)$ For some cases.

Comment: Okay. But there are not for $a = 1$, $b = -1$, and $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Is this a joke? Of course, that's not what I said.

Comment: @individ, I hope I have not offended you. My issue is that I'm actually not sure *what* you have been trying to say, so I haven't known how to respond. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is the trivial solution $\tilde{t}=(t_1,t_2,\cdots ,t_n)=(0,0,\cdots ,0)$. Now write $$\displaystyle h_2(\tilde{t})=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i^2\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i\right)^2\ge 0$$ where equality only occurs when everything is zero. I suppose I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, the question was actually that simple. Somehow I realized that $h_2 = (\sum t_i)^2 - (\sum_{i \neq j} t_i t_j)$ without picking up on this expression, which really does make it that obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Anisotropic in $\mathbb Q_2.$ In particular, if
$$  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + y z + z x + x y \equiv 0 \pmod 4,  $$ then $x,y,z$ are all even. That does it: if there is any integer triple that gives actual $0,$ we can divide through by the gcd of $x,y,z$ to get a primitive representation of $0.$ This little fact about $4$ says that there is no primitive triple  that gives actual $0,$ therefore there is none at all.

The same argument fails for 4 variables, your $n=4.$ The relevant prime is $5.$ Easy to get divisibility by $5,$ there are $10$ terms, make each $t_i=1.$ It remains easy to get divisibility by $25,$ take your $    t_1=1,   t_2= 2, t_3 =  3, t_4 =   19
$

For an example where real numbers give a different answer from integers, consider $$ w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 6 z^2.   $$ If $w,x,y,z$ are integers and the form $ w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 6 z^2   $ is  divisible by $9,$ then $w,x,y,z$ are all divisible by $3.$ So, $ w^2 - 2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 6 z^2 =0  $ is impossible for nontrivial quadruples in $\mathbb Q_3 $ and in  $\mathbb Z. $

Comment: I noticed that modular arguments weren't helping me for $n=4$. Why is the relevant prime 5 for $n=4$?

Comment: @jdc, the primes that are allowed to make a difference divide the discriminant, which (in even dimension) is the determinant of the matrix for the doubled form, which is also the Hessian matrix of second partials. In dimension $n,$ that determinant is $n+1.$ In odd dimension, you just divide by $2$ to get the "discriminant." For $n \geq 5,$ all forms are isotropic at all primes; there was a small chance $n=4$ would work, but no.

Answer (score 0):

Such decisions can be recorded.
Although I like this equation:

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$

And solutions:

$a=p^2-2tps+(3k^2+t^2)s^2$

$b=p^2+3(k+t)^2s^2$

$c=4p^2-4tps+4t^2s^2$

$d=3p^2+6kps+(3k^2+t^2)s^2$

And more:

$a=7p^2+2(3k-t)ps+(3k^2+6kt+7t^2)s^2$

$b=7p^2+6(k-t)ps+3(k-t)^2s^2$

$c=p^2+2(3k+t)ps+(3k+t)^2s^2$

$d=3p^2-6(k+t)ps+(3k^2+6kt+7t^2)s^2$

number $t,k,p,s$  integers and set us.